# Floating elements are rendered inaccurate in Webkit browsers

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, webkit, css-float

## Introduction

I created a grid using floating li-elements, mainly for design and click-handling reasons.

When I positioned another element over this grid using position:absolute, I noticed that the floating li-elements are not rendered correctly/miscalculated. In fact, these elements are a little bit smaller as they should be. It also looks like the y-Axis is much more inaccurate than the x-Axis.

I also tried to use *%* instead of *vw* but that doesn't help.

I think this is a bug in Webkit.
Is there any workaround?

## Example (Test in Safari/Chrome OSX)

Hover tiles next to the absolute positioned element to see the miscalculation.

### HTML

```
<ul>
    <!-- 10 -->
    <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>

    <!-- Repeat a few times ... -->

    <li class="absolute"></li>
</ul>
```

### SCSS

```
* {margin:0;padding:0;border:0;}

ul {
    list-style:none;
    width:100vw;

    li {
        float:left;
        width:10vw;
        height:10vw;
        background-color:#CCC;

        &:hover {
             background-color:#AAA;
        }
    }

    .absolute {
        position:absolute;
        top:50vw;
        left:50vw;
        background-color:#DDD;
    }
}
```

## Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

## JSFiddle

Test in Safari: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7Lrss69u/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I have observed the same issue in Chrome but not in Firefox. Why don't you reach to the `li` element you want with `:nth-child(n)` pseudo class? Especially when you need the element for click and hover events. find a working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7Lrss69u/3/)

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the styling and it works fine:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
}
li {
    float: left;
    width: 10%;
    height: 10vw;
    background-color: #CCC;
}
li:hover {
    background-color: #AAA;
}
.absolute {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50vw;
    left: 50vw;
    background-color: #DDD;
}
```